# lodash aliases: whether to use or not?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lodash provides aliases to various function.

For example, `_.each` is an alias to `_.forEach`, `_.eachRight` is an alias to `_.forEachRight` etc.

What is more advisable to be used here with a future maintenance perspective,
or in other words, when should one use aliases.

Comment: Are these aliases officially endorsed by `_` and there for your convenience? Or are they deprecated compatibility fallbacks? The documentation should tell you, and that's what you base your decision on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are here because in others libraries (or in the javascript Array prototype), this functions have different names. For example, the equivalent of `each` for a javascript Array is `forEach`. This aliases are useful in the documentation if you know a function in an other library and you want to find the equivalent in lodash/underscore.

If you want to code "pure lodash/underscore", you should not use aliases. Because it's way easier to find a function in the documentation with its original name.